# Chart.js scatter plot data not working with array constants from php

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm attempting to use chart.js to make a scatter plot graph with arrays as the x and y values. I'm getting the contents of these arrays from a sql query using php earlier in the file. It seems to work when I put in integers but not with my const arrays. I used a very similar method to display line graphs but I am having issues with the scatter plot. I am also quite new to JavaScript so that isn't making things easier. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```js
    const e80_array = <?php echo json_encode($e80_result_array) ?>;
    const e110_array = <?php echo json_encode($e110_result_array) ?>;

    const e80_avg_array = <?php echo json_encode($e80_avg) ?>;
    const e110_avg_array = <?php echo json_encode($e110_avg) ?>;

    const e80_serials= <?php echo json_encode($e80_serial) ?>;
    const e110_serials = <?php echo json_encode($e110_serial) ?>;

    // console.log(e80_array);
    // console.log(e80_avg_array);
    // console.log(e80_serials);

    const e80data = {
    labels: e80_serials,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'E80',
            data: [
                {x: e80_array, y: e80_avg_array}
            ],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]};

    const e80config = {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: e80data,
    options: {
        hoverRadius: 15
    }
  };
 
  var e80Chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('e80Chart'),
    e80config
  );
```

I've made sure my sql queries gather the correct data and form them into arrays properly. when I console.log(e80_array) and console.log(e80_avg_array) I get in web browser console...

```
Array [ "172", "172" ]
```

and

```
Array [ "197.0", "193.0" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you provided the `data`. The format

```
data:[
    {x: [....], y: [....]}
]
```

is not recognized by charts.js.

If you want to display `e80` *and* `e80_avg` with respect to `e80_serials`, you should define two datasets:

```js
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'E80',
            data: e80_array,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'E80_avg',
            data: e80_avg_array,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
        }
    ]}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp2hk9wj/).
In this case, a `line` chart type would have been easier.

If you want to plot `e80_avg` with respect to `e80`, you'll have to make each pair of data as an item: `[{x: 172, y: 190}, {x: 172, y:183}, ....]`

```js
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'E80',
            data: e80_array.map((x, i)=>({x, y: e80_avg_array[i]})),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev7jgfxa/1/).
In this case you don't need the labels.

Comment: Much appreciated kikon!